# Why the volume is higher when earphones' jack is not plugged in completely?

Tags: linux, audio, sound-card, headphones, headphone-jack

This is interesting.

When I plug in the jack completely the volume is normal as it should be, but the interesting part is that if I do not plug it completely but leave around 2 mm. of the jack outside the volume is much more higher. The quality is same - not only one ear is heard, not only playback without vocal, no sizzling etc.

Any ideas why this happens?

The laptop is Lenovo ThinkPad T530, the OS is Linux Mint 13 LTS x64, the earphones are ordinary Pioneers with 3.5mm jack.

Comment: Likely the switch that detects earphones has not been activated, so the amp is sending full power to the "speakers".